# Teechart .Net - Searching for sample examples

Tags: .net, teechart

This really seems to be a very stupid question, but I am not able to find examples for Teechart at the link "steema.net/TeeChartForNET". I have been searching through and all sources seem to point at this link for examples. However on this page, it asks for authentication username and password and when I enter my customer number and password, it does not accept it.

(PS. I am using an evaluation version)

I really need to check out sample working examples to get my chart going. I have tried a lot of code and am not able to display the chart on the page.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Thanks @Narcis. I found the sample examples at the mentioned location. I copy pasted the code from the sample example to a page in my application and still the chart does not show up. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Here is my code

ASPX Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestTChart.aspx.cs" Inherits="Recovery_TestTChart" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="tchart" Namespace="Steema.TeeChart.Web" Assembly="TeeChart" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <tchart:WebChart id="WebChart1" 
                style="Z-INDEX: 107; LEFT: 24px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 60px" runat="server"
                Width="432px" Height="290px" Config="some long key"
                TempChart="Httphandler" AutoPostback="False" 
                GetChartFile="GetChart.aspx"></tchart:WebChart>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASPX.CS Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Recovery_TestTChart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Steema.TeeChart.Chart ch1 = WebChart1.Chart;
        ch1.Series.RemoveAllSeries();
        ch1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bubble());
        ch1.Series[0].FillSampleValues();
        ch1.Legend.Shadow.Visible = false;
        ch1.Legend.Visible = false;
        (ch1.Series[0] as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bubble).Pointer.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.PolishedSphere;
    }
}
```

I have also added a file by the name of GetChart.aspx in the same directory as this page.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, we can not reproduce the issue with http://www.steema.net/TeeChartForNET/index.aspx. Anyway, you should find the full project at the *Examples* folder included with your TeeChart installation, for example: *C:\Program Files\Steema Software\Steema TeeChart for .NET 2012 4.1.2012.09280\Examples\TeeChartForNET*.